# Software Engineering Component Repository Tool

Tags: repository, components

I'm working as a software engineer for a company. We are going to apply some software engineering standards in our development process. We need a tool which provides a repository for our peripheral products (functions, classes, libraries, ...) which is created during software development process for later use. The tool should provide some functionalities (e.g Name of the component, it's functionality, withing which projects it is used?, author, publication date, list of known bugs, user rating, comment, ...) and it's better to have a web-based interface. Does anybody know such a software?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [FogBugz](http://www.fogbugz.com). Its a great project management tool which has recently released [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/learnmore.html?section=TrackReviewsWithFogBugz) which is source control you can integrate with your projects.

A cheaper alternative is to look at something like [XP-Dev](http://www.xp-dev.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I checked all of them but I don't need a version control system like svn I want something like a document manager. Please read my question one more time. I need something to make a repository of our sidelong products during the process of software development such as reusable functions, classes, and libraries. I want a tool to keep them all and give me the ability to manage them (e.g. Give access rights to people (maybe from Active Directory) to read/write them, write some notes about their usage, ...).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, such a tool doesn't exist because the problem is solved differently. Companies typically use component frameworks, whether their own or 3rd party, and develop new components that conform to the component standard from their framework.

Each project then depends on the framework rather than on specific versions of specific components. This also resolves interdependencies and all related version compatibility issues.

Component framework is typically documented somewhere by its vendor and newly created components can be added to your company's wiki, such as [mediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Alternatively, the company may need some [knowledge management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_management). See the introductory [videos](http://www.kbpublisher.com/kb/79/) from [kbPublisher](http://www.kbpublisher.com/). kbPublisher is an OpenSource Knowledge Base which may be even more suitable than a groupware like mediaWiki. The free version of kbPublisher can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbpublisher/).

Note each project should have a feature which displays the framework version number and configuration, as needed by staff. This way, when you are targeting a particular client, the system can be identified remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Open source tools like GIT or SVN may provide source code management however they may lack in the functions you are asking particularly bugs or ratings. There are also many paid tools available in the market which not only provides source code management but also management and integrations over projects. You may explore:

TFS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server
Rational Clear Case http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/clearcase